# Get all children of a nested tree recursively

Tags: php, laravel, recursion, recursive-query

Thanks everyone 
I have a JSON nested tree that I want to retrieve only ids.
This is the result of my query.
My goal is to call a recusrive function and give it the parent id and it will return all children Ids. 
**Ps: I'm working with laravel, Eloquent**

```
[{
"id": "1",
"name": "albert",
"children": [{
    "id": "5",
    "name": "George",
    "children": [{
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Julia"
    }, {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Harry",
        "children": []
    }]
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Richard",
    "children": []
    }]
}]
```

I tried to make a recursive function but it doesn't work.

```
function displayArrayRecursively($childrenUnit) {
foreach ($childrenUnit as $unit) {
    $ids[] = $unit->id;
    if ($unit->childrenUnit) {
        displayArrayRecursively(Unit::find($unit->id)->childrenUnit);
    } else {
        return $ids;
    }
}}
```

any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me

```
<?php
$jsonString = '[{
"id": "1",
"name": "albert",
"children": [{
    "id": "5",
    "name": "George",
    "children": [{
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Julia"
    }, {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Harry",
        "children": []
    }]
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Richard",
    "children": []
    }]
}]';

$objects = json_decode($jsonString);

function findIds($child, $ids) {
    if (isset($child->children)) {
        if (count($child->children) > 0) {
            foreach ($child->children as $ch) {
                $ids[] = $ch->id;
                $ids = findIds($ch, $ids);
            }
        }
    }

    return $ids;
}

$result = array();
if (count($objects) > 0) {
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        $ids = findIds($object, array());
        $result[] = array('id' => $object->id, 'ids' => $ids);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Input :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Query Reporting and Analytics
            [id] => 598
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [605] => Array ([name] => Access query [id] => 605 )
                    [606] => Array ([name] => Powerful [id] => 606)    
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Business Intelligence Platform
            [id] => 599
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [849] => Array ([name] => Access, explore [id] => 849)
                    [850] => Array ([name] => Advanced reporting[id] => 850)
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Data Management
            [id] => 600
        )
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 598
    [1] => 605
    [2] => 606
    [3] => 599
    [4] => 849
    [5] => 850
    [6] => 600    
)
```

Check following function for getting ids in tree.

```
function findTreeIds($tree, $ids = array(), $colName = 'id', $childColName = 'children')
    {
        foreach ($tree as $element) {
            if (!isset($element[$colName])) {
                continue;
            }
            $ids[] = $element[$colName];

            if (isset($element[$childColName]) && count($element[$childColName]) > 0) {
                $ids = static::findTreeIds($element[$childColName], $ids, $colName, $childColName);
            }
        }
        return $ids;
    }
```